# Flask with Jinja issue with pagination after the first page

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have created a dropdown menu to search for parts by project number from an SQL database. The first page loads with the correct parts but any pages subsequent give the error of:

> TypeError: show_compound() missing 1 required positional argument: 'search_string'

From what I've seen online it seems I may need to use `*args` or pass the `search_string` to the template but I am unsure of how to use `*args` or where to insert the `search_string` value on the template.

```
@parts_database.route('/searchcompound', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def compounds_search():
    form = ProjectSearch(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        search_string = form.select.data.project_number

        return show_compound(search_string)

    return render_template('parts_database/search_compounds.html', form=form)

@parts_database.route('/showcompound', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def show_compound(search_string):
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)

    pagination = PartsTable.query.filter_by(project_number=search_string).order_by(PartsTable.part_number).paginate(page, per_page=15, error_out=False)

    compound = pagination.items
    page_10 = pagination.next_num+9
    if page_10 > pagination.pages:
        pageincrement = pagination.pages
    else:
        pageincrement = page_10

    page_decrement = page - 10
    if page_decrement < 1:
        page_decrement = 1

    return render_template('parts_database/showpartstable.html', compound=compound, pagination=pagination, pageincrement=pageincrement, page_decrement=page_decrement)
```

template :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% import "_macros.html" as macros %}

{% block title %}Amos{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <a href="{{ url_for('main.render_csv', jobname_filename = 'Parts_PDB') }}"><h1>Parts</h1></a>

{% include 'parts_database/_showpartstable.html' %}
    {% if pagination %}
    <div class="pagination">
    {{ macros.pagination_widget(page_decrement, pageincrement, pagination, '.show_compound') }}
</div>
    {% endif %}
</div>    
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a view takes an argument, you must include that variable in the route.

In your case, you are missing `search_string` in your `show_compound` route definition. Try something like this:

```
@parts_database.route('/showcompound/<search_string>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def show_compound(search_string):
    (...)
```

EDIT:

Also, I'd sugest to redirect instead of calling another view's function.

Replace this:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    search_string = form.select.data.project_number

    return show_compound(search_string)
```

with this:

You'll have to import redirect before that:

```
from flask import redirect  # (Add this at the top)

(...)

if form.validate_on_submit():
    search_string = form.select.data.project_number

    return redirect(url_for('parts_database.show_compound', search_string=search_string))
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Although the last page of the results now have the error of                                                                                                                 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: @Chelsea that seems to be related to this line: `page_10 = pagination.next_num+9`. I'm not sure what's your logic here, but if you want the 10th page in a variable, why not do `page_10 = 10`?  Also, check my edit for another small tip. Please mark the answer as accepted if you don't mind, thanks!

Comment: Thank your your help. It was used when the search results just pulled all the compounds from the database previous to searching from project numbers but can be taken out now as there are far fewer result pages from the search via project.